# how to stay the color of the button when hit like and refresh page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

the default color of my like button is gray and when user hit like button it will run the togglepost "like" and the color will change to red.. i use ajax to insert the data if the user hit like the button... and if the user hit the like button again when its red it will run the togglepost "dislike" and the data from my db will be removed..

**button like**

```
<div class="boxcoracao">
    <span class="coracao" name="like"><br>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Love</span>
</div>
```

**jquery function**

```
<script>
$(".like").click(function(){ 
   $('.boxcoracao .coracao',this).toggleClass("ativo");
   var lpid = $(this).closest("div#buttons").find("#likepid").val();
   var lmid = $(this).closest("div#buttons").find("#likemid").val();
  if ($('.boxcoracao .coracao',this).hasClass("ativo")){  
  // update the text to show what the next click would be
    togglePost("like", lpid, lmid); // run function 
    alert("succes");
  } else {
   // update the text to show what the next click would be
    togglePost("dislike", lpid, lmid); // run function
     alert("failed");
  }



function togglePost(action,lpid,lmid){

  $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "../controller/like_controller.php",
        data: "action="+action+"&postid="+lpid+"&postmember="+lmid,
        success: function(data){
          window.location.reload();
        },
        error: function(e){
         alert("please try again...");
        }
      });
 }

}); 
</script>
```

here is my **sql query**....

```
    function UpdateLikes($postid, $postmember, $likeid, $action){

        if ($action == "dislike"){
         $sql = "DELETE FROM plike WHERE pl_puid = '$postid' AND pl_uid = '$likeid'";
            var_dump($sql);
        $result = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $result->execute();
        return $result->rowCount() ? true : false;
        } else{
        // before inserting you might want to check if they alredy liked or not before adding their count again.
        $query = "INSERT INTO plike SET pl_puid='$postid',pl_memid='$postmember',pl_uid='$likeid'";
            $query = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
            var_dump($query);
            $result = ($query->execute() ? true : false);
            return $result;
        }

  }
```

here is the gif button..

[image]

but my problem is when a user hit the like button and refresh the page the like button will reset to gray instead of red..any idea on how to solve this?.. when user hit like it will be red and when user refresh the page the button will still be red unless the user hit the button again to unlike?..

Comment: when the user hits the like button you will be needing to update it on your database. Are you sure you do that? Because I don't see any of that happening in the code you posted.

Comment: yes sir.... i do that i have ajax to save the data to my database i just didnt include it on my post but the like and unlike is saving on my db.. the only problem i have is when i refresh/reload the page the button becomes gray again even if i already hit the like button..

Comment: if that's the case then you must be doing something wrong with the `ajax` show us the `ajax` to help you better.

Comment: see the update above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to do some Ajax to save the state in your database or some cache on the filesystem for example.

If you want something less robust, you could save the state in a cookie or localstorage. Or even less persistent: in a session variable, that will be gone once the Browser session is lost.

Then when the page is requested check against the presence of your state in database, cache, cookie, session or whatever and give the button the corresponding class in your HTML.

If you are using PHP, for example, it could be done like so:

```
<?php
$buttonClasses = ['coracao'];
$didLike = your_read_from_cache_function();

if ($didLike)
    $buttonClasses[] = 'ativo';
?>
<div class="boxcoracao">
    <span class="<?= implode(' ', $buttonClasses) ?>" name="like"><br>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Love</span>
</div>
```

Comment: i already done that its not just included on my post but the saving part is done but the only problem left is when i hit like button and reload the page supposedly the button become red but not it becomes gray when i reload the page.

Comment: I updated my answer. You’ll, of course, have to read from the database in a function and find out if the user did already "like" – replace the `your_read_from_cache_function()` in the example accordingly.

Comment: can you give example for the your_read_from_cache_function?? base on my post above?..

Comment: Sorry, you gotta at least try. **Hint:** Gotta be a function that checks the database with `SELECT plike FROM…` and returns `Boolean`.